# How to get the current value of attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which gets get data from database, each column contains a button which gives the review of that particular row in modal box, modal box contains next and previous button, next gives the details of next row of table and previous give the previous data of the row. Now my question is:

I am able to do next and previous for only once?

```
 $('#review_essay').delegate('.navBtn', 'click', function () {
     var current_row_id = $(this).parents('#review_essay').attr('current_row_id');
     var position_value = $(this).attr('position_value');
     var navValue = parseInt(current_row_id) + parseInt(position_value);
     alert(current_row_id)
     alert(position_value)
     alert(navValue)
     var qid = $('#essay_data').find('tbody').find('tr').eq(navValue - 1).attr('qid');
     alert(qid);
     var uid = $('#essay_data').find('tbody').find('tr').eq(navValue - 1).attr('uid');
     var paper_id = $('#essay_data').find('tbody').find('tr').eq(navValue - 1).data('paper_id')
     var session_id = $('#exam_details').attr('session_id')
     var exam_id = $('#exam_details').attr('exam_id')
     //alert('reached');
     navigate(exam_id, session_id, paper_id, qid, uid);
 });
```

It does not performs more than once. the `current_row_id` will remain `0`.

Comment: Could you provide a copy of your html

Comment: Can you isolate the problem with jsfiddle and give us a link so we can check it out? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I see `delegate` which version of jQuery you are using

Answer (score 0):

The one problem I'm seeing is you are not updating the `current_row_id` so update it to `navValue`

```
$('#review_essay').delegate('.navBtn', 'click', function () {
    var current_row_id = $(this).parents('#review_essay').attr('current_row_id');
    var position_value = $(this).attr('position_value');
    var navValue = parseInt(current_row_id) + parseInt(position_value);
    alert(current_row_id)
    alert(position_value)
    alert(navValue)
    var qid = $('#essay_data').find('tbody').find('tr').eq(navValue - 1).attr('qid');
    alert(qid);
    var uid = $('#essay_data').find('tbody').find('tr').eq(navValue - 1).attr('uid');
    var paper_id = $('#essay_data').find('tbody').find('tr').eq(navValue - 1).data('paper_id')
    var session_id = $('#exam_details').attr('session_id')
    var exam_id = $('#exam_details').attr('exam_id')
    //alert('reached');
    navigate(exam_id, session_id, paper_id, qid, uid);

    //update the current_row_id to the new value
    $(this).parents('#review_essay').attr('current_row_id', navValue);
});
```